# IZpack java condition debugging (IZpack 4)

Tags: java, debugging, conditional-statements, stack-trace, izpack

I'm running izpack version 4 and I'm trying to use a java condition.

Java class (minus imports and try/catch) - 
**Edit** - version.properties is located in the root of my Test.jar file

```
public class Test {
    public static boolean testResult() {
        boolean goodVersion = false;
        Properties versionProperties = new Properties();
        InputStream is = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("version.properties");
        versionProperties.load(is);
        String minimumVersion = versionProperties.getProperty("com.test.version");
        String currentVersion = "2";
        if( Integer.parseInt(currentVersion) - Integer.parseInt(minimumVersion) >= 0) {
            goodVersion = true;
        }
        return isCompatible;
    }
}
```

Iz condition:

```xml
<condition type="java" id="compatibleVersion">
  <java>
    <class>com.Test.Test</class>
    <method>testResult</method>
  </java>
  <returnvalue type="boolean"/>
</condition>
```

The java code returns true if I run it in it's own jar or if I run java -classpath myInstaller com.Test.Test (with a main method calling the static method)

However when I run the izpack installer the condition remains false (as the catch declares false)

I've run java -DTRACE=true -jar myInstaller.jar and I can't see any stacktrace from my jar. I've tried writing to C:/output.txt when catching with the same result (runs fine outside the installer or when invoked with classpath but not when installer runs)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the error output from my external jar packaged in an izpack installer?

Answer (score 1):

Calling your installer jar using

```
java -DTRACE=true -DSTACKTRACE=true -DLOG=true -jar myInstaller.jar
```

will make it log to `C:Users\you\AppData\Local\Temp\IzPack_Logfile_at_...`

Answer (score 0):

As nobody seems to have an answer for debugging I thought it might be helpful to post the issue. In this case the problem was my iz.xml.

```
<returnvalue type="boolean"/>
```

should read

```
<returnvalue type="boolean">|||expected return value|||</returnvalue>
```

and will therefore return true or false depending on whether the expected return value matches the return value.